# Shift identity column value down in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem with a table with this structure

```
ID  Name       Code
-------------------
2   Counter 1  1001
3   Counter 2  1002
4   Counter 3  1003
```

`Id` is an `identity` column and is the primary key for the table.

Now I want to make change and shift up id to following format:

```
ID  Name       Code
--------------------
1   Counter 1  1001
2   Counter 2  1002
3   Counter 3  1003
```

User data is very important and never be changed

Thank you very much

Comment: If you care about the actual numeric values in an identity column, you're using them wrong. You ought to treat these as purely system generated blobs that happen to fit in numeric columns and uniquely identify rows - that's their job, not anything else. They shouldn't really be visible to your users so the actual values shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: Changing a key is very seldom a good idea, since any references from other tables may very well break. You should instead write your queries to not count on the numbers being consecutive, just unique.

Comment: Since you **cannot** change/update the value of an identity column once it's set, the only option you have is to create a new table with the identical structure and copy over the data, providing new values for the `ID` column in the `INSERT`. Seems like an awful lot of work - for what purpose, really???

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. But if you still want to shift the values, then try below script.

```
     SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON;

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) NewID
        FROM TableName
    )
    UPDATE CTE 
    SET ID = NewID

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF; 

    DECLARE @SeedValue INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName);

    DBCC CHECKIDENT ("TableName", RESEED, @SeedValue);
    GO
```

**DBCC CHECKIDENT** will reset IDENTITY seed value to total no. of row present in the table, hence next time when you will insert a new row it will produce the next consecutive value for IDENTITY column.

Comment: `Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot update identity column 'ID'.`. Even `IDENTITY_INSERT` won't help you here.

Comment: dear nithin thank you very much but i have a problem with SET ID=NewID i get a error in this line with "invalid column name"

Comment: then turn off the IDENTITY column using "SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF" and once the updating part is done enable it again using "SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON".
I have updated the query, have a look.